# Application of Doob's maximal inequality

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Consider a sequence of predictable processes $H_n$ converging to a predictable process $H$, each of which is bounded.

Consider $$E \left[  \sup_{t \in [0,T]} \left| \int_0^t (H_n(s)-H(s)) dM(s) \right|^2 \right]  \leq 4 E \left[ \left| \int_0^T (H_n(s)-H(s)) dM(s) \right|^2  \right] $$ where M is an $L^2$ martingale.

Where does the factor $4$ comes from? Wouldn't Doob's maximal inequality would only yield a factor of $2$?

Comment: You seem to be missing a power of 2 on $|...|$ (on both sides of the inequality).

Comment: @JohnDawkins: Yes you are right. But where is the factor 4 coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factor of $4$ comes from Doob's maximal inequality. For a martingale $X_t$, the inequality is usually written in the following form:
$$|| \sup_{t \in [0,T]} X_t ||_p \leq \frac{p}{p-1} || X_T ||_p \qquad (\star )$$

In your case, $p = 2$, so that applying $(\star )$ for the martingale $X_t = \int_0^t H_n(s) - H (s) dM(s)$ we get (in expectation notation):
$$\sqrt{ E \left[ \sup_{t \in [0,T]} \left| \int_0^t H_n(s) - H (s) dM(s) \right|^2 \right] } \leq \frac{2}{2-1}\sqrt{ E \left[  \left| \int_0^T H_n(s) - H (s) dM(s) \right|^2 \right] }$$

Squaring both sides you get the factor of $4$:

$$E \left[ \sup_{t \in [0,T]} \left| \int_0^t H_n(s) - H (s) dM(s) \right|^2 \right]  \leq 4E \left[  \left| \int_0^T H_n(s) - H (s) dM(s) \right|^2 \right] $$

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot the square root.

Comment: $X_t$ is a martingale, since $E[\int_0^T (H_n- H) d <M>(s)] <\infty$. That follows from the fact, that $H_n,H$ are bounded and   $E[<W>(T)] < \infty$ (since $M$ is a $L^2$ martingale)